# How to debug a python code where the execution starts from a python script which is in a different module?

Tags: python, debugging

I've two different python modules, 'module1' with execution scripts and 'module2' with test case scripts. I'm running the test cases through a script in modue1 which execute the test cases in module2.

**python3 /module1/execute.py -f /tests/testcase1.py**

How can I use pdb to debug my test cases. I tried adding breakpoints in my test cases and start the debugger. But, when I execute the test cases through script, debugger doesn't stop at break points.

Comment: Have you tried `python3 -m pdb  /module1/execute.py -f /tests/testcase1.py` ?

Comment: yes @Walfits I tried that.. but the debugger didn't stop at mreakpoints when I gave 'c' command

(pdb) c

Comment: Even if after having done `python3 -m pdb /module1/execute.py -f /tests/testcase1.py` you use, for example, `b 10` to set a break point on line 10?

Comment: @Walfits I use pycharm IDE and set break point from editor, because setting through command line using `b 10` for example is setting the breakpoint at line 10 in  `/module1/execute.py` rather in `/tests/testcase1.py`

Comment: Hi @Walfits I set breakpoint now by using `b /tests/testcase1.py:10` and it worked. thanks or your help!